# How to use yaourt on arch linux under proxy?

Tags: arch-linux, software-installation, proxy, http-proxy, yaourt

How do I install applications using yaourt under proxy network.
For pacman I can simply use:

```
export http_proxy=http://usernm:passwd@link:port
sudo -E pacman -S application
```

But how do I do this for `yaourt` as it is not used with `sudo` priveledges.

Answer (score 11):

I would advise to use a solid proxying tool for all (or most) of your proxy needs.

`$ proxychains4 yaourt -S application`

[proxychains-ng](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/proxychains-ng/) works well - but be sure to configure `proxychains.conf` before using.

Answer (score 7):

You can edit `/etc/sudoers` with the `visudo` command and add this line

```
Defaults env_keep += "http_proxy https_proxy ftp_proxy"
```

This pass the current user environment variables to the command excecuted under sudo, is the same as `sudo -E some_command` but automatically, you need this because yaourt internally uses `sudo pacman` and not `sudo -E pacman`

This is the Arch wiki page about [Proxy Settings](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Proxy_settings#Keep_proxy_through_sudo)